# bootstrap template working on index.html but not on any react components?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

Good day to anyone who interested on seeing this post!

Hi, I've been working on a react application and excited to do a bootstrap template integration the thing is that everything works alright but the responsiveness of the template it does not make any animation it just have the looks.

Working index example:
[animation when scroll down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Efwmn.png)

Not working react-component example:

[animation not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKeR1.png)

the index code is this one:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
 <link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
/>

        <!-- Favicon -->
        <link rel="icon" href="img/core-img/favicon.ico">

        <!-- Core Stylesheet -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/style.css">


        <!-- ##### All Javascript Script ##### -->
    <!-- jQuery-2.2.4 js -->
    <script src="js/jquery/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Popper js -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap/popper.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap js -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- All Plugins js -->
    <script src="js/plugins/plugins.js"></script>
    <!-- Active js -->
    <script src="js/active.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

the Header.js code:

```
   import React, { Component } from 'react'
import '../App.scss';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

export default class Header extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                    {/* ##### Header Area Start ##### */}
                    <header className="header-area">
                    {/* Navbar Area */}
                    <div className="palatin-main-menu">
                        <div className="classy-nav-container breakpoint-off">
                        <div className="container">
                            {/* Menu */}
                            <nav className="classy-navbar justify-content-between" id="palatinNav">
                            {/* Nav brand */}
                            <a href="index.html" className="nav-brand"><img src="img/core-img/logo.png" alt /></a>
                            {/* Navbar Toggler */}
                            <div className="classy-navbar-toggler">
                                <span className="navbarToggler"><span /><span /><span /></span>
                            </div>
                            {/* Menu */}
                            <div className="classy-menu">
                                {/* close btn */}
                                <div className="classycloseIcon">
                                <div className="cross-wrap"><span className="top" /><span className="bottom" /></div>
                                </div>
                                {/* Nav Start */}
                                <div className="classynav">
                                <ul>
                                    <li className="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="about-us.html">About Us</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Pages</a>
                                    <ul className="dropdown">
                                        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="about-us.html">About Us</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="rooms.html">Rooms</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="blog.html">News</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="elements.html">Elements</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Mega Menu</a>
                                    <div className="megamenu">
                                        <ul className="single-mega cn-col-4">
                                        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="about-us.html">About Us</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="rooms.html">Rooms</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="blog.html">News</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="elements.html">Elements</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <ul className="single-mega cn-col-4">
                                        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="about-us.html">About Us</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="rooms.html">Rooms</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="blog.html">News</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="elements.html">Elements</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <ul className="single-mega cn-col-4">
                                        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="about-us.html">About Us</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="rooms.html">Rooms</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="blog.html">News</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="elements.html">Elements</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <ul className="single-mega cn-col-4">
                                        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="about-us.html">About Us</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="rooms.html">Rooms</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="blog.html">News</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="elements.html">Elements</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                                </ul>
                                {/* Button */}
                                <div className="menu-btn">
                                    <a href="#" className="btn palatin-btn">Make a Reservation</a>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                {/* Nav End */}
                            </div>
                            </nav>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </header>
                    {/* ##### Header Area End ##### */}

            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

the app.js code is this:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.scss';
import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import Header from './components/Header';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
    <Header />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

what should i change or install

already done a "npm install bootstrap" "react-router-dom" "npm install node-sass"

ideas are running out and would be nice to have some tips thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

I Would recommend using the [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction) module. It has good documentation and is modular so you only import the components you need.

Steps involve:

- `npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap`
- include `bootstrap.min.css` cdn in your `index.html`
- include `bootstrap.bundle.min.js` as script tag just above closing body tag
- import `bootstrap.min.css` into root `index.js`

After this you should be able to import the components from the react-bootstrap library as needed. I've created a sandbox with a jumbotron and modal window below.

https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-wozniak-4wpvi?file=/src/App.js:42-92